# What is the best source of windows form applications?

Tags: windows, forms

I want to learn windows form applications but ı didnt find a source.I need help.Yesterday ı found some sentence which one textbox1->text=.... or x=converto.Int32 something like theese.Also my knowledge of win app is 0.Can anybody suggest a source please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Form Application Development your best source for information would be [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx). Here's another link for [Getting Started with Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229601(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope that helps.